# sinatra start as daemon programmatically

Tags: ruby, sinatra, daemon

Right now, after having loaded everything my executable runs my app like this:

```
Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App
```

and it works, but it blocks the terminal (which is ok for development)

How do I get this to start as a daemon programmatically from within my executable?

EDIT:

Code I use to start sinatra as a daemon:

```
    if options[:daemonize]
        pid = fork {Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App}
        File.open(pid_file_loc, 'w') {|f| f.write(pid)}
        Process.detach(pid)
    else
        Rack::Handler::pick(['puma']).run VCK::App
    end
```

Code I use to stop Sinatra Daemon:

```
Process.kill(15, File.read(pid_file_loc).to_i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can daemonize any ruby process from within your code by using [Process#daemon](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Process.html#method-c-daemon)

Comment: This is not a daemon, it's just a process running in the background with its standard output/error going to the console.  And once the shell is closed the sessions will receive a HUP signal and close the ruby process.  At the very least one should do something like "nohup ruby server.rb > /var/tmp/server.out 2>&1 &" to prevent the process from closing on the hangup signal.

Comment: This is a gem which can manage this background process for you since they have removed it from puma by default now. https://github.com/kigster/puma-daemon